# JUnit for void delete method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to JUnit and trying to learn. How can we write a JUnit for a void method. 
I have a delete method which is void. I am writing the test like below but its not working. 
Please suggest.

Method for which I have to write test case.

```
public class DoseService {
  @Autowired
  private DoseRepository doseRepo;

  public void deleteDose(int id) {
    doseRepo.deleteById(id);
 }
}
```

My Test

```
@Autowired
private DoseService doseService;

@MockBean
public DoseRepository doseRepository;

@Test
public void testDeleteDose() {

    Dose dose = createDose();
    ArgumentCaptor<Dose> arg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Dose.class);
    doseService.deleteDose(dose.getDoseId());
    verify(doseRepository).deleteById(arg.capture().getDoseId());
    assertEquals("120", arg.getValue().getDoseValue());
}

private Dose createDose() {
    Dose dose = new Dose();
    dose.setDoseId(1);
    dose.setDoseValue("120");
    return dose;
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Updated**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at verify(doseRepository).deleteById(arg.capture().getDoseId());
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: "is not working". What does that mean?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' ? assertion error?

Comment: I have updated the exception i am getting while running the test. Please find in the updated section

Comment: There's no exception posted, and no updated section.

Comment: @ErikPragt It have been added now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A unit test should test ONLY the class it is written for. So no need to inject real object, only mocks. Also you don't need a Dose object, as the only thing you want is to test the DoseService object.

I would do the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)//for JUnit 5, but you can add the JUnit 4 annotation
public class DoseServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private DoseRepository doseRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private DoseService sut;//System Under Test

    @Test
    public void testDeleteDose() {
        int doseId=42;

        // perform the call
        sut.deleteDose(doseId);

        // verify the mocks
        verify(doseRepository, times(1)).deleteById(eq(doseId));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its works fine. This way we can test the void methods.

Comment: One doubt. If we have custom save method which is void and is present in dao(Repository Inteface) which extends CrudRepository. In that case How can we verify that and what ?

Comment: Just test every class by itself. So isolate every class. It should be tested without triggering the classes it depends on. It is a good way to use dependency injection to be able to isolate all classes. Try to verify every call that is made to every mocked dependency. Use captors to get parameters passed to mocks.

Comment: ```sut.deleteDose(doseId);``` when called this line i think return ```NoSuchElement``` Exception

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are verifying the `delete` method, but in your code, you are using the `deleteById` method.

This code should work:

```
verify(doseRepository).deleteById(arg.capture()); // changed to deleteById
assertEquals(dose, arg.capture());
```

Comment: I have placed the wrong test case earlier. I have changed it.  Still I am getting exception

Comment: No worries, but you still haven't explained what kind of error you get

Comment: i have added the exception. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In the mocked action you need to capture the argument. And then you can assert anything you want based on the captured argument.

Maybe something like this?

```
verify(doseRepository).deleteById(arg.capture());
assertEquals(dose.getDoseId(), arg.getValue().getDoseId());
```

Comment: yes i was going wrong the correct code will be as you suggested. After i did the modification. Now i am getting NullPointerException in the same line.

Comment: Well, your update is not strictly the same. But in any case, check Sven’s answer, he shows the correct approach for what you want to achieve.