# How to Mock deleteById using mockito in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

How to Mock **mockRepository.deleteById()** using mockito in spring boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit for void delete method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734415/junit-for-void-delete-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on where you want to use this mock. For integration tests running with the `SpringRunner` it is possible to annotate the repository to mock with the `MockBean` annotation. This mocked bean will be automatically inserted in your context:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SampleIT {

    @MockBean
    SampleRepository mockRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // ... execute test logic

        // Then
        verify(mockRepository).deleteById(any()); // check that the method was called
    }
}
```

For unit tests you can use the `MockitoJUnitRunner` runner and the `Mock` annotation:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

    @Mock
    SampleRepository mockRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // ... execute the test logic   

        // Then
        verify(mockRepository).deleteById(any()); // check that the method was called
    }
}
```

The `deleteById` method returns void, so it should be enough to add the mock annotation and check if the mocked method was called (if needed).

You can find more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean)